# I can't use Xcode simulator in VSCode (CocoaPods error)

Tags: xcode, flutter, simulator

Working with Flutter I tried to use `Xcode` simulator and I get the error in the picture.

I searched everywhere and following all the possible solutions but nothing is right (`gem install commands`, `pod install(*[!] No Podfile found in the project directory*.)`, `brew commands...`).

However, if I tried the last app that I made and I have no problems running the simulator. Why with this project? Thank you in adv!

```
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.26.0-2.0.pre.131, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H15 darwin-x64, locale fr-FR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AMNZ.png)

Comment: Have you tried a "flutter clean"?  How about "flutter doctor -v"?

Comment: I updated my post @RandalSchwartz. Yes, Flutter doctor all good.

Answer (score 0):

**Redit:**

I figured it out. So it was missing 'a folder' or 'a file' in the IOS folder (either with or without Pods folder).

I do not know what was it to be more specific since I just change the directory (`cd <your iOS folder>`) and then recreate or update the folder (<`flutter create .`> .
You'll see that something will update then you can either try the `pod install` command or give it a shot and try the simulator (remember to go back to your project folder though) .